# Не могу подключиться к удаленной БД с помощью pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Суть в том, что с локальным MySQL сервером МАМР все работает.
Вот кусок кода:

```
   import pymysql
 
   USER = 'root'
   PASS = 'root'
   HOST = 'localhost'
   PORT = 3307
   DB = 'base'

   CON = pymysql.connect(user=USER, password=PASS, host=HOST, port=PORT, database=DB)
```

Теперь мне нужно подключиться к базе данных на удаленном сервере (хостинг ISPServer).

```
USER = 'master'    
PASS = 'password'       
HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'  
PORT = 1500          
DB = 'base'
```

Но ничего не происходит, приложение просто висит, нет ни ошибок, ни подключения.
В phpMyAdmin база данных работает корректно, отвечает на запросы, создаются таблицы и т.д.
Как правильно подключиться к удаленной базе данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все в порядке, просто на моем тарифе невозможно подключиться удаленно к БД

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).