# pymysql подключиться к базе данных сайта

Tags: python, база-данных, pymysql

Уже не первый день пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных. Ничего не получается.

```
   import pymysql
 
   USER = 'user'
   PASS = 'pas123'
   HOST = '188.240.120.20'
   PORT = 1500
   DB = 'base'

   CON = pymysql.connect(user=USER, password=PASS, host=HOST, port=PORT, database=DB)
```

после запуска скрипт просто висит порядка нескольких минут, потом ошибка подключения. Если порт добавить в хост после двоеточия, то сразу выкидывает ошибку.

Если запустить локальную базу данных, то код работает без нареканий, но мне нужно подключиться именно к удаленной БД. phpMyAdmin работает, таблицы открываются, изменения вносятся.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу подключиться к удаленной БД с помощью pymysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%91%d0%94-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-pymysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была со стороны сервера

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).